# Probable minimun of a set having only Maximum, Average and the number of values

Tags: statistics, average

I have a data set in which I am given the number of values, the average and the max, how can i work out the probable min value?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any assumption on the distribution? do you know something about the variance? i think you need some more information, posed as it is i dont think there is a single determined value, that is the most likely minimum

Comment: You can bound the minimum below by assuming all the values but one take the maximum value and above by assuming all the values but one take the minimum and the other the maximum. Other than that you will need some further assumptions or data

Comment: Thanks foe the comments, I have not further info. to be more precise the data i have is for a variable number of values, if there are at least 5 values  return then i am given the average for the values ranked 1-5 if there are at least then i get the averages of 1-5 and 6-10

Comment: Sounds similar to a German Tank Problem.

Comment: I had looked at the German Tanks Problem and thought it might be applicable.

Comment: Alas it isn't as I'm looking for the min amount which is the highest the serial number you find using the GTP. I've gone with assuming that the Avg is the mode and there is linear regression, and its looking sort of sensible